# ssh port forwarding (tunneling) in linux

Tags: linux, openssh, portforwarding, tunneling, ssh-tunnel

I have a specific scenario that I want to solve. I currently connect to a host via port forwarding:

```
 laptop -> gateway -> remote_server_1
```

and another host:

```
 laptop -> remote_server_2
```

with passwordless login working on both. Neither of the remote servers are visible to the outside world. Now I'm running a service on remote_server_2, that I'd like to be able to access on remote_server_1. I presume I have to setup reverse port forwarding from remote_server_1 to my laptop, and then on to remote_server_2, but I'm not sure how to do this. Anyone come across this situation before?

**Edit:
The full solution in case anyone else needs it:**

```
mylaptop$ ssh -L 3001:localhost:3000 server_2
server_2$ netcat -l 3000
```

Then setup the tunnel via `gateway` to `server_1`:

```
ssh -t -t -L 3003:server_1:22 gateway
```

Then access it from `server_1`:

```
ssh -R 3002:localhost:3001 -p3003 localhost
echo "bar" | nc localhost 3002`
```

and hey presto `server_2` shows `bar` :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do exactly as you've described. Setup the server on `server_2`.

```
mylaptop$ ssh -L 3001:localhost:3000 server_2
server_2$ netcat -l 3000
```

Then access to it from `server_1`.

```
mylaptop$ ssh -R 3002:localhost:3001 server_1
server_1$ echo "foo" | netcat localhost 3002
```

`server_2` will show `foo`.

Comment: This nearly works, except I have to tunnel through to server_1 as well. So if I do:

    mylaptop$ ssh -L 3003:gateway:3002 server_1

and

    mylaptop$ ssh -R 3003:localhost:3000 -p3003 localhost

am I on the right lines? Helpfully server_1 doesn't have netcat on it (I don't have admin rights on that one)

Comment: Sorry just realised netcat is nc on there. Anyway it's not quite working yet.

Comment: I'll give you the accepted answer, as it gave me enough clues to go on - full answer in my edit.